# Matlab MCR missing internal class

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, matlab-deployment

Executing Matlab on my Ubuntu machine with MCR 8.3 installed and configurated, I have this error:

```
The class "internal.optim" is undefined.
Perhaps Java is not running.

Error in internal.optim.presolve (line 211)
Error in ipqpcommon (line 30)
Error in quadprog (line 353)
Error in mv_low_level_solver_quadprog (line 72)
Error in mv_optim_min_risk (line 47)
Error in Portfolio/estimateFrontierLimits (line 79)
Error in portafoglio (line 63)

... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...
file /home/zuno/.mcrCache8.3/Portaf0/toolbox/optim/optim/+internal/+optim/presolve.p, name presolve, line 211.
file /home/zuno/.mcrCache8.3/Portaf0/toolbox/optim/optim/private/ipqpcommon.p, name ipqpcommon, line 30.
file /home/zuno/.mcrCache8.3/Portaf0/toolbox/optim/optim/quadprog.m, name quadprog, line 353.
file /home/zuno/.mcrCache8.3/Portaf0/toolbox/finance/finance/@Portfolio/private/mv_low_level_solver_quadprog.p, name mv_low_level_solver_quadprog, line 72.
file /home/zuno/.mcrCache8.3/Portaf0/toolbox/finance/finance/@Portfolio/private/mv_optim_min_risk.p, name mv_optim_min_risk, line 47.
file /home/zuno/.mcrCache8.3/Portaf0/toolbox/finance/finance/@Portfolio/estimateFrontierLimits.m, name estimateFrontierLimits, line 79.
file /home/zuno/.mcrCache8.3/Portaf0/PortafoglioB/portafoglio.m, name portafoglio, line 63.
com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: The class "internal.optim" is undefined.
Perhaps Java is not running.
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclFeval(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.access$600(MWMCR.java:23)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$6.mclFeval(MWMCR.java:833)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$5.invoke(MWMCR.java:731)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.mclFeval(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.invoke(MWMCR.java:406)
```

Obviously Java is running and if I try to execute other Matlab functions I have no problems.
What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**
If I execute the same code, with the same MCR, on Windows... It works...

Comment: Looks like a bug in the .p function `presolve`. Is this a standard toolbox? If yes, you should raise the issue with MathWorks, because you cannot look into the .p functions (as opposed to .m functions)

Comment: It's a standard toolbox... But on Windows it works.

Comment: If you look at the message error, it says that the CLASS `internal.optim` doesn't exist. Obviously he thinks that a package name (given by the path .../+internal/+optim/) should be a class; usually this happens when calling a global function as a method, or when you change the interface of a class but you don't do `clear classes` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it was compiled on Windows. 
Starting from v83 the produced jar that contains the converted libraries also contains a .ctf file that is zip like package containing the Windows DLLs.
To solve this problem you should recompile your jar (I know that it sounds strange because java motto is write once run everywhere but ...it's not a java problem) with linux at 64bit.

Cheers,
VD